# Converter RSS para JSON Google Feed API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, rss

A algum tempo estava usando o serviço do google `google feed api` porem este serviço foi descontinuado, gostaria de saber se existe alguma solução para substituir, estou fazendo assim com jQuery:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=2.0&q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.theguardian.com%2Finternational%2Frss',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {}
 });
```

Existe algum plugin ou no próprio método `$.ajax` algo que posso fazer?

Comment: O problema é converter rss para json ou o solução para o serviço que foi descontinuado?

Comment: Eu gostaria de um serviço similar, encontrei aqui e resolveu pra mim: http://ibacor.com/api#bcr-xml-converter

Comment: Responda sua pergunta com a descoberta @LennonS.Bueno, para deixar a solução disponível pra outros usuários! :)

Comment: @LucasCosta respondido :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uma alternativa que encontrei foi utilizar o http://ibacor.com/api#bcr-xml-converter e ficou assim:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://ibacor.com/api/xml-converter?u=http://rss.uol.com.br/feed/noticias.xml&f=json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {}
    });
```

Obs. Estou utilizando o feed do UOL.